# class_copyIvarList leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getArrayValue:(NSArray *)array{
     NSMutableArray *valueArray = [NSMutableArray array];    //value数组
    for (NSObject *object in array) {
        unsigned int numberofIvars = 0;
        Ivar* ivars = class_copyIvarList([object class], &numberofIvars);
        NSMutableArray *objectArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(const Ivar* p = ivars; p< ivars+numberofIvars;p++){
            Ivar const ivar = *p ;
            NSString* key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:ivar_getName(ivar)];
            NSString *value = [object valueForKey:key];
            [objectArray addObject:value];
        }
        [valueArray addObject:objectArray];
    }
    return valueArray;
}
```

I'm having a memory leak when using this method.
What chould I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    free(ivars);
    return valueArray;
}
```

According to the documentation: "You must free the array with free()"

(https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/objcruntimeref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_copyIvarList)